# EJB and isCallerInRole: wrong output with multi-roles check in SessionContext

Tags: java, ejb, roles, sessioncontext

I have a problem with `isCallerInRole` method from the `SessionContext`. The application run on Glassfish 2.1 and uses JDK6.

In the following class, I'm exposing two methods that ascertain if the current user has a specific role or not. In particular, I'm going to check for two specific roles, say `Role1` and `Role2`. `CheckRemote` is the interface for `CheckFacade`.

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles({"Role1", "Role2"})
public class CheckFacade implements CheckRemote {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public Boolean hasRole1() {
        return ctx.isCallerInRole("Role1");
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean hasRole2() {
        return ctx.isCallerInRole("Role2");
    }
}
```

When I go to call `hasRole1()` or `hasRole2()` I always get `false` as result, even if the user has the role.

Now, if I consider the following version that is focused only on one role, then everything works fine, i.e. I get `false` or `true` if the user has not the role or has the role, respectively.

```
@Stateless
@DeclareRoles("Role1")
public class CheckFacade implements CheckRemote {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public Boolean hasRole1() {
        return ctx.isCallerInRole("Role1");
    }

}
```

Maybe I'm missing something. Any idea?

Comment: I have the exact same error here. Did you find what is wrong?